# Transparent Layout...?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout

i have a requirement...i want transparent layout(80% transparent like that), so that the background should visible. Is there any way to do the same..????

I tried that(But not working..that second linear layout should transparent)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#C0C0C0">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip" 
        android:background="@drawable/style">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
     <style name="YourTheme" parent="android:@Theme.Translucent">
           <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
     </style>
</resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="background">#55000000</color>
</resources>
```

but its not working.
That 2nd linear laout should be transparent.

Thanks.....

Comment: Can you please post a snap of what you are getting ? and transperent means what?do you want your wallpaper to be seen under your semi transperent background?

Comment: ya exactly...you got my requirement. wallpaper to be seen under semi transperent background..????.

Comment: But then you can not do that for a portion of your xml.you can make your complete activity to be transperent.please see http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TranslucentBlurActivity.html and http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TranslucentActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

the theme parent="android:@Theme.Translucent" is correct but the issue is change your layout size as per the requirement and then implement the theme in the manifest file for that activity. this should work. remember the layout height and width should be explictly mentioned

Comment: use layout height and width instead of fill parent eg.200dip

Comment: Actually i want transparency in a particular layout not for the whole activity. eg in a linear layout wallpaper to be seen under semi transperent background.

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is the solution of your problem....

You can range it from 00 to FF (Hexa Decimal)

For maximum transparency => #00555555 (Here 00 stands for the alpha)

For minimum or no transparency => #FF555555 (Here FF stands for the alpha)

you can set the alpha for your LinearLayout like this :

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);


ll.setAlpha(0.4);
```